# Cluttering sound during braking and turning at low speeds when ABS is active

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, abs, shock-absorber, aveo

This is a 2008 Chevrolet Aveo sedan.

I am having issues with my brakes. When I step on the brakes at low speeds while driving in my complex where there are speed bumps, I hear a cluttering sound that I can feel from my pedal.

The unusual thing is, when the ABS light is on, everything works perfectly but just when it turns off the cluttering sounds and pulsing from the pedal starts again. This only happens when I am driving at slow speeds. Occasionally the park light is also on, but the hand brake is actually disengaged.

Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: Check brake fluid level and see how to test your abs sensors on each individual wheel

Answer (score 1):

Get your codes read and go from there. You're probably going to need a new wheel speed sensor or harness. If you scope or graph the WSS PIDs you'll probably see the signal dropping out. When the ABS light comes on it will disable the system.